# Space between hexagons in SVG

Tags: svg

I've tried to make some hexagon-based map in SVG. Unfortunately, there are white spaces between fields.

I've disabled fields' borders (stroke="none stroke-width="0"), rounded all floating points to integers and made sure that hexagons have common points (no space between them). It didn't help.

Two screenshots shows same SVG in different magnifications https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zta2b.png

Source code is here: http://pastebin.com/hqwTKW4M (remember to change extension to svg, after download).

Comment: I use Firefox (14.0.1), Opera (12.00) and Chromium (22.0.1197), but it doesn't matter. I knew this is issue of SVG rendering engine. In SVG specification, I found info about shape-rendering property [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty). After I set it to 'crispEdges' or 'optimizeSpeed' for my hexagons, white gaps disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting shape-rendering property to 'crispEdges' for all hexagons (or group of them) solves this issue. E.g.

```
<polygon
  points="0,90 45,12 135,12 180,90 135,168 45,168"
  fill="green" stroke="none" stroke-width="0"
  shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty

Comment: Setting crispEdges will make the outer edges look jagged, for a nicer effect set a stroke that will cover the gaps, e.g. `stroke="green" stroke-width="1.5"`

Comment: I will be using quite complex fill (pattern) so I can't use this trick. I have to cover gaps, even I will loose edges' smoothness.

Comment: This worked for me, but I eventually want to convert my svg to pdf where the gaps show up again. Any similar solution for PDF?